# How to design ER diagram to allow for retrieving of product option pricing data?

Tags: database-design, sql, domain-driven-design, normalization

I'm looking for a way to organize database tables when it comes to handling product option pricing retrieval and also storing pricing history for my use case.

**What I have**

I have a custom-made `product` that has various product `options` and belongs to a product `category`.  I want to be able to query `current price` for product options, and keep `price history` for reference/auditing purposes.  `Category` is effectively a "product group".

Each product is custom-made to order, assembled from options upon customer request.  There are no pre-configured products and product price is the sum of selected `option` prices.  There is no concept of a single product price.

**I want to answer questions like**

1. What is the current price for option X of product Y? (price retrieval)
2. What was the price for option X of product Y last year? (auditing & history)

Note:  each `category` (aka "product group") has a valid set of `options` and each individual product model has its own price for each `option`.  For example, say Category X has option named Y.  Product model 10 in category X prices option Y at $10.  Product model 20 in the same category prices same option at $20.

**What I have**

[image]

I think the above corresponds well to my needs - I have products which belong to various categories, where products have various options based on various available categories they belong to, and `category_has_options` defines available valid product option relations.

**Price Lookup and History Design**

What I am thinking is having two tables like so:

[image]

`price_lookup` table that will allow me to answer question #1.

`price_history` table that will allow me to answer question #2.

I am having trouble figuring out how to connect those tables to my existing schema.  Is there a design that will suit me well for my purpose?

Comment: You have the arrows pointing the wrong way. Arrows go from the many table to the one table, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A price category is the combination of several options and features.
- But those options and features must me applicable/available for those products
- You assemble different price categories out of available options and features for a given product
- You have a price history table ofr each price category, so no price is lost
- No need to have separate price tables

**A PNG is worth 1024 words:**

[image]

**Simpler version assumming feature and option is the same thing, added detail on prices:**

- Some restrictions cannot be modeled and have to checked with a sanity check procedure like for example that there is not date overlapping for the same price/product/category ih historical table.

[image]

Update:

- PRICE_CATEGORY is a master table and OPTION_CATEGORY is it's detail. So a price category is like a combo/product that adds many things to the main product. Those things are in OPTION_CATEGORY.
- The FK from OPTION_CATEGORY to AVAILABLE_PRODUCT_OPT is to make sure tou cannot add options/features to a product that do not apply to it, like adding a ashtray to a motorcycle.
- OPTION_CATEGORY only has FKs to the other two tables

**An even simpler model:**

[image]

- Products and options are in the same table, after all options are products too.
- A column indicates whether a product is a base product or an option.
- Being a single table, a single historical price table is necessary.
- The `OPTION` table is a many to many between products and themselves indicating which options are theoreticatlly available for each product (no astrays for motorcycles)
- A trigger on `OPTION` must garantee that only base products have options.
- PRODUCT_COMBO is a named combo which consistes of a base product and one or more options.
- Obviously only options relevant to a product can be added to a combo.

Comment: thanks but wow, 9 tables(!!)  For my purposes `feature` and `option` are probably more or less interchangeable, aka. different names but similar concept - an add-on to the base product.  Otherwise if I become adamant about naming them exactly, each product category has different names for those add-ons -- there are probably 20-25 different add-ons across all product lines with their own product-specific names. As much as I like the conceptual decomposition, I am thinking 9 tables is a bit much...

Comment: Also I didn't see how `price_history` work just yet, but it basically needs to answer questions like: what's the current "active" pricing for this particular product & its options?  who made a change to the pricing, and when

Comment: fyi - see Note/Example update on my question

Comment: @Dennis I added a simple model with 6 tables and detail on how prices work.

Comment: @Dennis with the update it would go beyond 9 tables because you need historical prices for both base products and options.

Comment: thanks.  that is more manageable.  In my case it is safe and reasonable to assume that base price and option price will both change at the same time.  And even if base price remains unchanged while option pricing changes, it will be rare enough and acceptable enough to treat them in the same class as add-ons and not add extra complexity to the table schema

Comment: How are you making those pngs?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I make the models with Sybase Power Designer, and then I capture a portion of the screen.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I really need a Linux alternative that is as good as PD.

Comment: what is the purpose of `option_category` table?  I'm not quite seeing it.  i.e. what kind of data would go in there? what will be lacking if that table is removed?

Comment: @Dennis I added an update answering that. But I'm guessing I missunderstood your question. What you need is indeed more complex, because you need historical prices for both base products and and for the additional options/features.

Comment: @Dennis I provided a third, even more simple alternative. I think it's more like what you originally bargained for.

Comment: in your simpler alternative, how do you prevent me inserting an incompatible product into price_category table?
Example, I have product with id 1, that has no available product options.  And yet I can insert it into price_category table matching it up with some incompatible available_product option.

Comment: @Dennis To create a combo you first insert master record in the PRODUCT_COMBO table. Then you must insert options /addons in the detail table of that combo which is called COMBO_OPTIONS. You can only insert items into that table if a corresponding option exists in table OPTION. OPTION holds all compatible candidate OPTIONS for a given product. If you try to insert a row into COMBO_OPTIONS  the FK will only allow you to insert a row if that FK corresponds with the PK of a row in OPTION.

Comment: @Dennis Remember that in the simple version both base products and addons (options) are stored in the PRODUCT table. OPTION is a M:M table  with itself telling which products are candidate addons to what other products. If you don't have that, the person making up the combos would have to choose from hundreds of unrelated items that have no relation with the base product he intends to create  a combo with.

Comment: @Tulains: Thanks. I am getting close. Can you please checkout the updated answer, let me know if I am getting your suggested design right? I am choosing to go with the more complex design based on what I have - not going with the simplest one. Part of my roadblock was figuring out what data goes into what table and how the keys connect, so I have populated them with sample car data that fits my use case to help me with that.  I see that in the simple design though you have had `product_combo` and `combo_options` tables for which I used ? in my ER design as I did not see their purpose.

Comment: @Dennis I magine a combo at a McDonald's restarant. The product is the burguer and the combo options are pickles, fries, soda, extra cheese, etc. Get it?

Comment: I thought pickles, fries, soda, etc were the `options`.  How can they also be `combo_options`?  I guess I am still missing that part.  I think my `product category addon` table contains the valid available "combo options", so I don't see a need for "product combo" and "combo options" table that are on your design...  I may be mixing up designs though trying to correlated different ER into one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44849/discussion-between-tulains-cordova-and-dennis).

Answer (score 1):

**[Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/)**

Creating 3 different pricing tables and expecting developers to know which one is relevant 9 months from now is asking a lot.

Personally, I'd go with

```
price(id, price, start_date, stop_date)
```

and have a separate table for features:

```
productPrice(id, productId, priceId, option)
```

Using just a timestamp for your price has the benefit of not having to worry about 2 price records with overlapping dates.  However, it has the disadvantage that now your price records depend on each other - lose a single record and you know don't know the historic price anymore.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
[image]

`price_lookup` serves as an authoritative source for product-category-option definition.

`price_history` defines pricing for said product options.

Or this:

[image]

`price_history` serves as authoritative record of product option and also stores pricing history by date.  Best of both worlds!

To get current product price:

```
select amount
from price_history 
where product_id = X and option_id = Y 
and date_from <= NOW() and NOW() <= date_to;
```